# Breakpoint never hit when dll would be called

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have added a managed c++ dll to my c#.net project (using "add resource"); it finds the class I'm trying to instantiate just fine, no compiler errors. But somehow, fields I know I instantiated are getting null reference exceptions. So I put in a breakpoint at the top of the method that sets the field... and it's never hit. If I comment out the line using the class from the .dll, it hits the breakpoint. Uncomment that and the method never executes despite being called. What's happening here?

The dll is ManagedSpyLib, the class is [ControlProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164593.aspx?code=true&level=root,ManagedSpyLib&file=ControlProxy.cpp), if that helps any. The call is inside the DoWork method of a backgroundworker which is most definitely getting started asynchronously -- could that entire thread be crashing silently without even alerting the debugger? How can I debug this?

ETA: I couldn't find anything about the dll in the output window or the Modules window. Some googling found a fix: change the target to the .net 3.5 framework. But I'm no closer to understanding WTF is going on than before -- my code works, but now I have no idea why, which is even more puzzling. Can someone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: The debugging behavior is consistent with the exception.  And yes, exceptions in a BGW's DoWork() method are swallowed.  Don't forget to test e.Error in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  Or use Debug + Exception, Thrown checkbox to get the debugger to stop.

Comment: I don't know, you'd know better from what the debugger tells you.  You were otherwise complaining about NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant It was a null reference because the method I expected to have been called by that point in the program didn't run at all because of..... I have no idea, but something to do with .net 4.0. I don't see how "breakpoint not being hit because method was never entered" is "consistent with" a nullPointerException, as I put the breakpoint way before the object was being accessed.

Comment: Breakpoint didn't get hit => code didn't run => variable isn't getting initialized => NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 3):

Generic steps for debugging unknown errors/failure to stop at breakpoints:

Make sure you have PDBs loaded for DLL in question (Debug->Window->Modules). Make sure sources match the version you are using.

Check if there are any suspicious traces (especially about exceptions) in Output window while you are debugging.

Consider breaking on all exceptions (Debug->Exceptions -> "When thrown" for CLR exceptions). May need to disable "my code only" (Tools->Options->Debug->My code only) to break on *all* exceptions.

Comment: Well that led me to a fix via google, but I'm even more confused. See the question edit.